# Converting Perl Regex to PHP

Tags: php, regex, perl

I have the following Regex in PERL which I need to convert to PHP

```
if ($referrer_url =~ /\.$domain/) { }
```

I currently have the following in PHP to match it, but I'm not getting the same results:

```
if (preg_match("/\.$domain/", $referrer_url)) { }
```

Can anyone tell me if what I have is the same or if I'm mistaken? Thanks!

Comment: "I'm not getting the same results" - what is different with your results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im just guessing that your $domain probably contains .'s like mysite.com if that is the case you need to use [preg_quote](https://www.php.net/preg_quote) on the variable:

```
if (preg_match("/\.".preg_quote($domain, "/")."/", $referrer_url)) { }
```

Comment: Actually, the Perl code is closer to being equivalent to `if (preg_match("/\.".$domain."/", $referrer_url)) { }`, but it probably should be what you said.

Answer (score 2):

If $domain is a regular string you may prefer to use [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) to `Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string`. This would achieve the same result as using preg_quote with the benefit of being easier to read.

```
if (strpos($referrer_url, ".$domain") !== false) {
}
```

Comment: `$domain` is treated as a regex pattern in the Perl code, this is different, but this probably does what the Perl code should do.

Comment: Or just `if ( strpos( $referrer_url, ".$domain" ) ) { ...`  Yes, to my eyes, your solution *is* more readable than the `preg_match()` option. +1.